# PHP: Image not uploading to folder

Tags: php, html, database, upload

Hey guys I think i need a fresh set of eyes on this. I have an insert script that inserts data to the database along with the URL of an image that gets uploaded to a folder called uploads. The problem is that while all the information goes into the database the image never gets uploaded to the folder. Does anyone know why?

```
<?php
$date=$_POST['date'];
$title=$_POST['title'];
$body=$_POST['body'];
$month=$_POST['month'];
$file = $_FILES['file'];
$name = $file['name'];
$path = "uploads/" . basename($name);

$sql="INSERT INTO content (date, title, body, month, pic_id) VALUES ('$date','$title', '$body', '$month', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($path) . "')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

if($result && move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $path) ){
echo 'Query has been inputted into the database';
}

else{
echo 'An error occured';
}
?>
```

My html looks like this:

```
    <h1>Post A Blog </h1></br>
    <form name="personal_information" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="insert.php">    
            <label>
                <span>Date:<br></span><input id="date" type="date" name="date" />
            </label><br><br>
            <label>
                <span>Title:<br></span><input id="title" type="text" name="title" />
            </label><br><br>
            <label>
                <span>Body:<br></span><textarea id="body" type="text" name="body"/></textarea>
            </label><br><br>
            <label>
            <span>Month:<br></span><input id="month" type="text" name="month" />
            </label><br><br>
            <br>

Upload file:</br>
<input type="file" name="file" id="fileupload"></br></br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit"/>
```

Comment: What's the permission of the upload folder?

Comment: the folder has both read and write access

Comment: did you tried to check the returned value of move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $path) outiside of the IF () ?

Comment: Turn on all error reporting by adding this: error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1'); to the top of the file. It might be that you are exceeding the max-file size. I use ['tmp_name'][$key] when uploading the file.

Comment: cheers @AndrewGibson i tried that but still no luck.

Comment: Sorry, my comment "I use ['tmp_name'][$key] when uploading the file" is not relevant. Do you not see any error or warning messages?

Comment: no its displays my validation message but doesnt actually do the full job

Comment: Add the following early in your code: print_r($_FILES['file']['error']); and view the source for the page to read the output.

Comment: just gives the validation message.

Comment: @AndrewGibson cheers for your help i think i'll just go about it another way and see if that works

Comment: The mysql functions have been deprecated. You should change your code over to mysqli or PDO. Also, you need to escape the values coming from your POST. You're leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection.

Comment: `$file = $_FILES['file'];` and `$name = $file['name']; etc.` Your server's fighting to figure out **WHERE am I going to put this?**. Don't try to re-invent the wheel. Check out **Tizag's** example http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php

Comment: @user2480085 *FIRST* => **Get rid of** `$file = $_FILES['file'];` and `$name = $file['name'];` **and set your $path variable** `$path = "upload/";` **then** `$path = $path . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);`, **Replace your old one with** `if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path)) { echo 'Query has been inputted into the database'; }`.

Comment: @user2480085 P.s.: My bad, I forgot to add `$result &&...` in there. You'll figure it out, am sure.

Comment: @user2480085 Here it is in its entirety: **Get rid of** `$file = $_FILES['file'];` and `$name = $file['name'];` and do `$path = "upload/";` then `$path = $path . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);`, **Replace your old one with** `if($result && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path)) { echo 'Query has been inputted into the database'; }`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on my phone so can't give you an example but I'm pretty sure that you have to use the fullpath as destination.

try __DIR__ . '/'.  $path or use document_root

Comment: I don't believe the full path is necessary, it should default to the current location.

Comment: still dont work. the upload code runs fine on its own. thanks anyway man

Comment: If it is not you should get errors verify if display errors is on or check error logs maybe try to write a file to the directory (file put contents)

Answer (score 0):

**move_uploaded_file() -** Moves an uploaded file to a new location.

**is_uploaded_file() -** Tells whether the file was uploaded via HTTP POST

This will work for you:

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {
   echo "File ". $_FILES['userfile']['name'] ." uploaded successfully.\n";
}
```

[More detail and example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php)